# Removing names in array by distance

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array of venues like so:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [dist] => 5.421905274077098
        [name] => venue1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [dist] => 1.6506176672720143
        [name] => venue2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [dist] => 0.9541989204006235
        [name] => venue1
    )
```

I am attempting to remove any with the same name, but with a priority on distance, so in the example above the 3rd item would stay, and the first item would be removed. So far I have attempted looping through the array twice and unsetting any that have same name and less distance, but this does not appear to remove them

```
for($i=0 ; $i<count($returned) ; $i++) {
    for($j=0 ; $j<count($returned) ; $j++) {
        if(!$returned[$j] || !$returned[$i]) {
        } else {
            if($returned[$j]['name']==$returned[$i]['name']) {
                if($returned[$j]['dist']<$returned[$i]['dist']) {
                    unset($returned[$i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure your array looks like this? or may be array('name' => 'venue1', 'dist' => '100') and so on

Comment: you have mixed up `JSON + Array`

Comment: After your edit, all the names are unique .. so no items would get removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary array like this:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($returned as $item) {
    $name = $item['name']; // convenience variable

    if (!isset($result[$name]) || 
            $result[$name]['dist'] > $item['dist']) {
        // add or overwrite
        $result[$name] = $item;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, the `$result` array will effectively contain the items after removal.